# Product Relation removed automatically

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-relations

I am using Magento 1.13.1.0. and recently i found that the related products I assigned from Admin got removed after some time.  I check the cron and its already working fine.

Is there any other specific issue that remove the product relation ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you assign them manually or through a rule?

Comment: manually, 
i use magmi for importing this related product and also add some products manually , Initially it was setup to load using rule and manual both , but then I disable to load  the product rules base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento Provided a Patch file and Its under watch if this patch can fix the issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3udWHRsbBdAUVk2S0pjZ1dSLTA/view?usp=sharing